# Quote in POST content causing bad requests

Tags: c#, json, string, api, windows-services

I'm doing POST requests to an API via a Windows Service written in C# and the content varies. Some of the time, the users will use " to mean inches. This data must be passed to the API, but when it's done automagically, the way I've set it up, this causes it to end the description string in the POST content prematurely, resulting in a bad request.

For example, I might have a "description" field that looks like this:

"Replaced 4" pipe"

Is there a way to pass the " in the middle of the string without exiting the string? Could it be something like the following, or should I just replace the " character with the word "inch"? I would much prefer to send the actual double quote, since I'm not certain that they would *always* mean it to mean inches. *i.e. they may actually be quoting someone.*

```
        if (description.Contains("\""))
        {
            description.Replace("\"", "inch");
        }
```

Comment: You could escape the quotes with backslash(\\) when sending the POST request

Comment: how are you doing the post? most APIs would worry about this for you, but it *sounds* like you're missing the encode step, where `"` becomes `%22`, assuming this is raw `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data ? But: can we see how you're actually posting `description` to the server (along with whatever other fields)? (many other characters are affected by this; please don't just add a replace of `"` with `%22`)

Comment: plus if it's a json or xml body, you should use a proper serializer to serialize the content and escape illegal characters .

Comment: This is an HttpRequestMessage btw.

Comment: @jpb103 don't do that. Concatenating strings doesn't respect the proper escaping rules of JSON. Use a [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) to construct the body instead, which will respect character escaping when the object is serialized.

Comment: @TomW I just used what the API provider suggested in their API documentation for C# HttpClient requests. My answer below did work for me, though I do see your point in it probably not being the ideal solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer comes curtesy of @TomW...

"@jpb103 don't do that. Concatenating strings doesn't respect the proper escaping rules of JSON. Use a JObject to construct the body instead, which will respect character escaping when the object is serialized"

```
                JObject json = new JObject
            {
                { "account", account },
                { "description", description },
                { "abbreviation", abbreviation }
            };
```

Where account, description and abbreviation are all populated dynamically. This method properly respects the character escaping rules of JSON and prevents the POST errors I was seeing. Thanks Tom!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29992606)

Comment: @Filburt: It seems like this **is** a _proposed_ answer—although not one that's yet been _validated_.